# How can I make the tabbar corners transparent in React Navigation 5?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, menu, react-navigation, tabbar

So, I've added some props to my tabbar to round off corners of my tabbar:

```
tabBarOptions={{
          style: {
            height: 70,
            elevation: 0,
            backgroundColor: '#FDF5F1',
            borderTopLeftRadius: 15,
            borderTopRightRadius: 15,
          },
          showLabel: false
        }}
```

But behind my rounded corners is some white background:

[image]

How can I make it transparent or just make it disappear?